# How to do a OData query filter for a path in the Azure Logic App "Get Files" action?

Tags: odata, sharepoint-online, azure-logic-apps, sharepoint-api

The action "Get files (properties only)" is returning the properties of all files in a certain directory of a SharePoint document library. And when checking the output, I see that in the ODATA json is a field:

`"{Path}":"Report/xxx/Finalized_Reports/2014/2014_01/"`

With this Filter Query setting:
[image]
I get this warning:

```
{
"status": 400,
"message": "Column 'Path' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user."
}
```

If I do `substringof('text', {Path})` the error is

```
{
"status": 400,
"The expression \"substringof('test', {Path})\" is not valid. Creating query failed."
}
```

`substringof('test', ''{Path}''` gives me also the "expression is not valid" error.

`substringof('test', '{Path}')` this gives me this error

```
{
  "status": 400,
  "message": "The function operator 'substringof' is not supported or its usage is invalid."
}
```

If I do `susbstringof('text', Author)` the query does not fail. So, the function seems to be supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently OData filter is not supported in SharePoint Online connector. But we can implement your requirement by other solution, I provide a sample below for your reference.

We can use "**Get files(properties only)**" first and then use "[Filter array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#filter-array-action)" to do the filter.
[image]

The expression of `item()` in the screenshot above is:

```
item()?['{Path}']
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking your time. This is indeed good workaround to solve the logical problem, I give you an upvote for this nice workaround. The correct answer, you gave too, is that the "OData filter is not supported", at least for the path parameter. I tried all combinations of hand-over the Path JSON parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I have to take back my decision about the answer.
Meanwhile I found the solution: the parameters that can be passed are not the ones seen in the history output link of this action. The parameters you have to pass are the [internal field names](https://blog.softartisans.com/2009/12/08/list-of-internal-names-for-sharepoint-fields/) of a SharePoint document library.

The correct filter query is this:

```
substringof('test',FileLeafRef)
```